# Current 'Axis & Allies: War at sea' Rulebook?

Tags: axis-and-allies, axis-and-allies-mini

I recently a booster pack for this game, so I don't have the rulebook.

Reading in other sites and reading the website I found [the one listed here](https://www.wizards.com/default.asp?x=ah/aam/waratsea) but it appears that there is yet one more. I can't find a digital copy of it!

If there really is an electronic revised/newer rulebook, where can I find it?

Answer (score 1):

The page you linked has a "Quickstart Guide" and "Advanced Rules". What else are you looking for? That is, what did you see that led you to believe there is anything else?